# Multiple Passkeys for a Domain in iOS

Tags: ios, passkey

I have four accounts on google.com. I want to  add a passkey for every account by  scanning a passkey QR code. However, I can only add one passkey for google.com. When I try add a new passkey for a new account, it replaces the previous one. I understand that Apple allows one passkey for a domain.  Is it right ?